# Combine 3 arrays, find duplicates and compare price and take the cheapest one as well as unique value with price ascending order

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I want to run a script in PHP where we need to find duplicates and need to keep the cheapest pair from different array.

We have 3 suppliers (3 arrays) and we need to combine the 3 arrays and find the duplicates and from duplicates compare price and keep the cheapest one from duplicates as well as keep unique data too with sorting order price ascending.
Please find the below case.

Note: need to maintain time complexity.

```
$supplier_1[] = array("sr" => "101", "model" => "iphone7", "color" => "silver", "price" => "52000");
$supplier_1[] = array("sr" => "102", "model" => "iphone7", "color" => "gold", "price" => "48000");
$supplier_1[] = array("sr" => "103", "model" => "iphone8", "color" => "red", "price" => "60000");
$supplier_1[] = array("sr" => "104", "model" => "iphoneXR", "color" => "silver", "price" => "72000");
$supplier_1[] = array("sr" => "105", "model" => "Galaxy10", "color" => "black", "price" => "63000");

$supplier_2[] = array("sr" => "201", "model" => "iphone7", "color" => "silver", "price" => "43000");
$supplier_2[] = array("sr" => "202", "model" => "iphone7", "color" => "gold", "price" => "62000");
$supplier_2[] = array("sr" => "203", "model" => "Xaiomi", "color" => "yellow", "price" => "12000");
$supplier_2[] = array("sr" => "204", "model" => "S10", "color" => "Grey", "price" => "80000");

$supplier_3[] = array("sr" => "301", "model" => "iphone7", "color" => "gold", "price" => "63000");
$supplier_3[] = array("sr" => "302", "model" => "iphone7", "color" => "silver", "price" => "48000");
$supplier_3[] = array("sr" => "303", "model" => "Xaiomi", "color" => "yellow", "price" => "18000");
$supplier_3[] = array("sr" => "304", "model" => "S10", "color" => "Grey", "price" => "60000");
$supplier_3[] = array("sr" => "305", "model" => "S12", "color" => "White", "price" => "59000");


// DESIRED RESULT

$result = array(
    "0" => array("sr" => "203", "model" => "Xaiomi", "color" => "yellow", "price" => "12000"),
    "1" => array("sr" => "201", "model" => "iphone7", "color" => "silver", "price" => "43000"),
    "2" => array("sr" => "102", "model" => "iphone7", "color" => "gold", "price" => "48000"),
    "3" => array("sr" => "305", "model" => "S12", "color" => "White", "price" => "59000"),
    "4" => array("sr" => "103", "model" => "iphone8", "color" => "red", "price" => "60000"),
    "5" => array("sr" => "304", "model" => "S10", "color" => "Grey", "price" => "60000"),
    "6" => array("sr" => "105", "model" => "Galaxy10", "color" => "black", "price" => "63000"),
    "7" => array("sr" => "104", "model" => "iphoneXR", "color" => "silver", "price" => "72000")
);
```

Comment: how this is related  to mysql???

Comment: @scaisEdge because we are retrieving the data from DB from 3 different table

Comment: So you can done the job on MySQL side

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Can you tell me how can i compare and find the deduolicates and unique and cheapest values by joining 3 tables in a single query.

Comment: update your question add  the related  tables schema and the query you use for populate the array ..

Comment: “Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue. We expect you to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Here the solution:

```
//merge 3 arays to one
$suppliers = array_merge($supplier_1, $supplier_2, $supplier_3);
$result = [];

foreach ($suppliers as $s) {
    $key = "{$s['model']}-{$s['color']}";
    if (!isset($result[$key]) || $result[$key]['price'] > $s['price']) {
        $result[$key] = $s;
    }
}

print_r(array_values($result));
```

[PHP fiddle here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=0d87b46a604df27f9e71b5ddf24b2b6d&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Below MySQL solution:

```
select merged.*
from (
    select * from supplier_1
    union
    select * from supplier_2
    union
    select * from supplier_3
) merged
join (
  select model, color, min(price) min_price
  from (
      select * from supplier_1
      union
      select * from supplier_2
      union
      select * from supplier_3
  ) merged
  group by model, color
) groupped on 
    groupped.model = merged.model and
    groupped.color = merged.color and
    groupped.min_price = merged.price;
```

[MySQL fiddle here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=0d87b46a604df27f9e71b5ddf24b2b6d&sqlses=d55c9984e7f9ad3b188713e0367425fd&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)